# How to get Creative Cloud (CC) to work on Yosemite?

Tags: adobe, osx-yosemite, osx-yosemite-beta, creative-cloud

Creative Cloud says it has a mandatory update. I click Install, it says Failed to Update Creative Cloud Desktop. Contact Customer Support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it a problem with a design suite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I contacted Adobe support after a while and they helped me solve it. Here's the transcript with the steps. Notice that first we go to ~/Library and then to /Library (not same thing!):

Navin: Please close all the Adobe products that are open.

Navin: Click on Finder.

Navin: Click on Go> Go To Folder and type ~/Library and hit return

Navin: Navigate to location Application Support> Adobe

Navin: Delete OOBE, AAMUpdater, AAMUpdaterInventory folders.

Navin: Click on Finder. Click on Go> Go To Folder and type /Library and hit return

Navin: Delete OOBE, AAMUpdater, AAMUpdaterInventory folders

Navin: Click on Finder. Click on Go> Utilities

Navin: Delete Adobe Application Manager and Adobe Creative Cloud folder.

Navin: Now I will provide you with the link of the Creative Cloud Desktop.

Navin: https://ccmdls.adobe.com/AdobeProducts/KCCC/1/osx10/CreativeCloudInstaller.dmg

Navin: Open the above link and install it.

Alex Novosad: it is installed, should I sign in?

Navin: Yes, please.

Alex Novosad: Seems to work!

Navin: Great!

Alex Novosad: Installing Lightroom and PS now.

Alex Novosad: This didn't erase my Lightroom preferences, did it?

Alex Novosad: I had export presets there, etc.

Navin: It will be there. You can use it.

Alex Novosad: Cool, thanks for the help!